# Обработка нажатия клавиши в цикле while

Tags: pascal, циклы, клавиатура

Здравствуйте! Не могу придумать, как реализовать обработку нажатия клавиши в цикле while на паскале. Требуется, чтобы цикл выполнялся постоянно и выход из него происходил по нажатию клавиши Esc, но если использовать readkey, то при каждом шаге цикла ожидается нажатие клавиши.

```
while true do
begin
if readkey = #27 then break;
{Тело цикла}
end;
```

Comment: А почему не отмечается, что вопрос касается операционной системы MS DOS?

Comment: т.е. хочешь сказать, что под виндоус 7 не будет данный код работать?

Comment: Я не видел windows7, а под его предшественниками досовские программы исполняются виртуальной дос-машиной. Но под другими виртуальными машинами можно выполнять и программы для совсем других операционок.

Comment: Этот код всегда будет работать в той системе, для которой был скомпилирован.

Answer (score 4):

```
if keypressed then readkey
```

В общем виде, когда я писал код на паскале в начале 2000, я использовал конструкцию:

```
repeat
if keypressed then
  begin
  key := readkey;
  case key of
  #27 : ...
  #0 : // поступил расширенный код
       begin
       key := readkey;
       case key of
       #... : // обработка расширенных кодов
       end;
       end;
  end;
  end;
until key = #27
```

В синтаксисе немного мог напутать, на паскале не писал десяток лет. Key : char;

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

Можно это также сделать ассемблерной вставкой. Функция возвращает код нажатой клавиш без ожидания ввода:

```
Function GetKey : Byte;
      Var     k : Byte;
      Begin
       asm
        mov  ah, $01
        int  $16
        jz   @2
        xor  ah, ah
        int  $16
        test al, al
        jz   @1
        mov  k, al
        jmp  @2
    @1: mov  k, ah
    @2:end;
       GetKey := k
      End;
```

Comment: Как данный код будет работать с функциональными клавишами, которые возвращают расширенные коды?

Comment: Писал этот код 3,5 года назад, но после вашего вопроса открыл давно забытую книжку товарища Зубкова, и кое-что вспомнил :)

При нажатии символьных клавиш в AL помещается их скан-код. При нажатии Функционлаьных клавиш в AL помещается префикс скан-кода (в случае для 84-клавишной клавиатуры - это 0), а расширенный код клавиши - в AH.

Так что при нажатии какой бы то ни было клавиши эта функция вернёт её скан-код. То есть для стрелочки вверх это будет 72, вниз - 80 и т.д.

Comment: Т.е. в данном случае, как я понял, на выходе мы можем получить одинаковый код как для символьной клавиши, так и для функциональной?.. Можно наверное конечно доработать код функции таким образом, чтобы она также возвращала признак была ли клавиша нажата функциональная, либо символьная. Например, возвращать 2 параметра, либо возвращать не byte, а integer.

Но кому это надо? =)

Comment: @Pincher1519, да такое может быть. И судя по [этой таблице кодов][1], функция на нажатие сочетаний Alt+R и Ctrl+S вернёт один и тот же результат. Правильный фикс - возвращать не один, а два байта (префикс + сканкод).

  [1]: http://pascal.toom.su/ReadKey#H41A43E43444B44143F43544643843043B44C43D44B44543A43B430432438448

Answer (score -2):

Если бы это был не паскаль, я бы создал второй поток, слушающий нажатия клавиш и по нажатию останавливал первый поток.

Comment: Да вы,батя, извращенец...

Comment: А паскаль-то в чём виноват (см. мой комментарий к вопросу)?

Но насчёт "извращенца" я с @embarcadero согласен...